# Scraping and Crawling-Issue a token

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I am a newbie to Scraping and Crawling. For a research project, I am trying to scrape and crawl the social network site: https://my-plant.org/

There is an API for this site: [Foundational API v1.0](https://pods.iplantcollaborative.org/wiki/display/docs/Foundational+API+v1.0#FoundationalAPIv1.0-AUTH)

It says this is how you issue a token:

```
curl -X POST -sku "vaughn:**********" https: //foundation.iplantc.org/auth-v1/ | python -mjson.tool
```

I'm trying to use php with the help of wikiscraper to get authenticated and into the site so I can scrape it. I am having a difficult time getting authenticated and into the site. I put the command above on a command line and was returned:

```
curl: No match.
python: module json.tool not found
```

Can someone help me get authenticated so I can begin crawling and scraping the site in php?

Answer (score 0):

Standard json module appeared in python2.6 (or 2.5.5?). Probably, you use the earlier python release.